# Laravel many to many relationship count

Tags: php, laravel-4, eloquent

I have a products model and a applications model. It has a many to many relationship between them. I have the pivot table which has the product_id and application_id to represent this relationship.

I need to get the count for each application.

I can do this by writing a query against the pivot table and do a group by application_id and have this as a method in the product model.

```
SELECT application_id, count(*) FROM products_applications group by application_id;
```

I was wondering if there is eloquent way to do this which is less taxing on the DB.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Can you try sth like:

```
DB::table('products_applications')
    ->select(['application_id'])
    ->addSelect([DB::raw('count(*) as product_count')])
    ->groupBy('application_id')
```